# how to add Button,ImageView widget in ListView control which fetch and shows record from sqlite database

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview, android-button, android-sqlite

```
i want to fill ** **Listview** **  Widget in android with Records from table of sqllite database and show the content of table's field using button and imageview widget.
```

if any example with sqlite database and image is available, it would help all the developer to develop his app

Comment: check this it has an image view and text which you can modify it as you wish to http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188364/setting-response-to-listview/10189653#10189653) might be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to customized listview ?

Comment: Dear Sharath.  You have given link to good example but i want to populate ListView control in xml file which contains TextView widget, Button and image Widget contain data and images fetch from database of sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customized listview.
Check out this link :

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

You have to create a xml layout file which consist listview within a liner layout.
And a lisviewstyle xml file for designing listview.

Hope this will help.
Cheers !!!

Answer (score 2):

This coding will help you.

In main.xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#302217"
        android:cacheColorHint="#333333"
        android:divider="#999966"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" >
```

And listStyle for designing listview

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp" >
    </TextView>
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </Button>
```

Create Method to retrieve data from database:-

```
public Cursor createBlacklist()
    {
        Cursor cur=null;

        try
        {
            sqliteDb=dncDb.getReadableDatabase();
            cur=sqliteDb.query("tableName", new String[]{"_id","fieldOfDatabase"}, null, null, null, null, null);


        }
        catch(Exception exce)
        {
            exce.printStackTrace();
        }


        return cur;

    }
```

Get ListView:-

```
Cursor cursor = createBlacklist();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
        String[] from = { "fieldOfDatabase" };
        int[] to = { R.id.txtView};
        SimpleCursorAdapter simpleListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                CreateBlackList.this, R.layout.liststyle, cursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(simpleListAdapter);

        ListView list = getListView();
```

Comment: Thank You Manish.    your example is easy to understand. but can you further explain how to use Button control in your example to delete a particular record from database table.

Comment: You can handle those buttons by using LayoutInflator